# How to insert into multiple table using single query?

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

I have two tables one is restaurantDetails and Another is its location. 
When any one want to add a new restaurant he/she have to insert the details and location as well. But the problem how do i insert into these two tables using a single stored procedure ?

Comment: Ummm. Two insert statements in the stored proc? I'm assuming there is some complicating factor why you couldn't do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the triggers, here is an example how you can insert the row into second table before inserting it in first table:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER second_table
BEFORE INSERT ON first_table
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF (EXISTS(SELECT * FROM first_table WHERE sp = NEW.sp)) THEN
    INSERT INTO second_table (col1,col2,col3)   
    VALUES (NEW.col1, NEW.col2, NEW.col3);
  END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

using ";" to separate each of them!
You stored procedure should look like:

```
create procedure 
(
@nameofNew varchar(100)
)
--Insert code for restaurantDetails
;
--Insert code for location
```